# Difference between AssociatedType vs Self.AssociatedType

Tags: swift, swiftui

Let's say I have this protocol:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

associatedType Item: SomeOtherProtocol

var itemValue: Item

}
```

What's the difference between that protocol and this one:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

associatedType Item: SomeOtherProtocol

var itemValue: Self.Item

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to the difference between `self.someProperty` and `someProperty`. Usually they refer to the same property, except in cases when something called `someProperty` is also declared in a more inner scope, like this:

```
struct Foo {
    let someProperty: Int
    init(someProperty: Int) {
        self.someProperty = someProperty
        // here, self.someProperty and someProperty mean different things
    }
}
```

For types, this occurs much more rarely. Off the top of my head, I can only think of situations involving a local type:

```
struct Bar {
    typealias Foo = Int
    
    func foo() {
        struct Foo {}

        // here, Foo refers to the local struct, but Self.Foo refers to the typealias
    }
}
```

Adding `Self.` (even when it is not necessary) can also clarify that you mean the type that is declared inside the current type, and not some other type declared globally.

```
struct Bar { }

protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Bar

    // though "Self." is not necessary,
    // it is now very clear which type I mean
    var property: Self.Bar { get }
}
```

That said, it is probably best to avoid situations like that in the first place, by naming your types better :)